# JSON hangs javascript, but only specific ones

Tags: javascript, json

Having a special one here.

Got a piece of javascript that asks for a bunch of data.

The function that asks for this information is:

```
    onRegionClick: function(e, code){
        var mapKeyUrl = "/GenMap/getcountry/jsonchk"
        $.getJSON(mapKeyUrl, {
            regsel: regsel,
            countryiso: code
        })
        .done(function( countrydata ) { 
            document.getElementById("maptext").innerHTML = "You are a " + countrydata.countryname;

        })
    }
```

If I click something on the map, it hangs.
So tried to changing the JSON request to another function that returns less data, but same format.
Works like a charm.
If I go to the same request in the web browser. the jsonchk returns:

```
{
   "country":[
      {
         "ccode":"ID"
      },
      {
         "cname":"Indonesia"
      },
      {
         "exturl":"N/A"
      },
      {
         "impdate":"N/A"
      },
      {
         "lupdate":"29/09/14"
      },
      {
         "impnote":null
      }
   ]
}
```

It will stop working if I press Indonesia. However, if I call another function returning different data, one called countln:

```
{
   "class":"genmap.Country",
   "id":101,
   "countryiso":"ID",
   "countryname":"Indonesia",
   "regstats":[
      {
         "class":"genmap.Regstat",
         "id":46
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: To state the obvious, check the browser's console for any errors..

Comment: user145400, I was going to say yes, then thought I would double check, and true enough, if I wait about two minutes I get Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, but only with this data (created two different JSON handlers, both sending the same info). There is also a load of build param lines, but not certain what would cause that, as the call only returns the data shown above.

Comment: So your web request returns the data fine.. If you exceed the call stack size then check what you are doing with that data. You might have some sort of infinite loop. BTW, the two JSON snippets you have are not the same format, unlike what you said.

Comment: In addition to this advice, be sure to not concatenate text into a context where it is supposed to be HTML.  When you do this, nothing is escaped opening yourself up to broke pages and injection issues.  Use `.text()` if you're setting text.

Comment: try add .error(function(data) { console.log(data); } ) after closing parenthesis of done() and show us the result.

Comment: user145400: Sorry, should have been clearer, they are similar and generated in a similar manner. But they are different, and I should really have been clearer as I think the cause is at least partially to do with the JSON

Comment: Brad: how do I use .text()      Moesio, no luck on adding error(function),

Comment: brad: Sorry about my ignorance, but the .text()

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why this one works (well, does not hang, still can't read the data) but it does, if someone have the same issues that is:)

```
var mapKeyUrl = "/GenMap/getcountry/jsonchk";
var mapKeyUrl = "/GenMap/getcountry/jsonchk"
$.getJSON(mapKeyUrl, {
    regsel: "${regsel}",
    countryiso: code
})
.done(function( contdata ) {
    alert(contdata)
    contdata = contdata.country
    alert(contdata)
    document.getElementById("maptext").innerHTML = "I am an abwrock " + code + contdata.exturl;
})
```

Comment: So, you are saying that changing `"You are a "` to `"I am an abwrock "` makes the code work? That's indeed odd.